# Is there a mathematical definition of Python's syntax and semantics

Tags: python, math

I've been looking for a mathematical definition of Python. Like there is for e.g. relational algebra from IBM. In some scripts of my uni courses, I find something similar but its more of an example language usually to explain some concepts. I would love to find something similar for Python.

Comment: There isn't any. CPython, the reference implementation, acts as the language specification.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: I believe that is not true. CPython is a *reference* but not the *specification*. For example, dictionaries were made to be ordered in CPython some versions before that became part of the specification. But that is semantic, not  syntactical, and the question is not clear which is wanted here.

Comment: A handful of languages, such as ML, have been completely specified by fairly mathematical theories of formal semantics. Most languages, including Python, have not been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relational algebra?   Computer languages like Python are *not* relational.

Perhaps you can find a [grammar](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) for Python.

Then you can feed it to a [lexer/parser](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) to get an abstract syntax tree [AST].  Once you have that, you can walk the tree and generate whatever you wish for each node (e.g. byte code, etc.)

This is the bread and butter of compiler design.

Comment: I know it's not Relational but there is a mathematical definition for this particular algebra contrary to python it seems

Comment: I'm not sure it's an algebra.  What does that word mean to you?  I'm not a mathematician, but I know a fair bit about math.

Comment: @phiStackOverFlow: The grammar for Python (see the link in the answer above) is a mathematical definition of the syntax of the language. Do you need that answer in a different, mathematical form? If so, you need to state that form more precisely. Or do you want a specification of the semantics of the language?

Comment: That was actually my original thought my. An array of integers would be defined by this, for example, int X int X ... X int -> T but I guess these answers are more then I could have asked for.

Comment: "If you would like to see a more formal definition of the language, maybe you could volunteer your time — or invent a cloning machine :-)." this is from the reference https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html